# What does "Make sure local comes before bind in nsswitch" mean?

Tags: likewise-open

```
Joining to AD Domain:   *******
With Computer DNS Name: (null)


Error: Required configuration stage not enabled [code 0x0000a606]

The configuration of module 'set computer hostname' is required. Please either allow this configuration stage to be performed automatically (by passing '--enable hostname'), or
manually perform these configuration steps and rerun the domain join:

The following step(s) are required:
    Give the machine a fully-qualified domain name. If performed automatically, the fqdn will be set through /etc/hosts to 'proj.users.campus', but it is possible to use a
    different fqdn and/or set it through dns instead of /etc/hosts. However in all cases, the fqdn must follow standard DNS naming conventions, and have a period in the name.
    The following steps will be used if the fqdn is set automatically:
        * Make sure local comes before bind in nsswitch
        * Add a loopback entry in /etc/hosts and put the fqdn as the primary name
```

The second error I think I have addressed. I don't understand the first one though.

What does **Make sure local comes before bind in nsswitch** mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does Make sure local comes before bind in nsswitch mean?

In /etc/nsswitch.conf in line "host: .." files before dns. Example:

```
Correct
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4  

Not correct
hosts:          dns files
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that in the /etc/nsswitch.conf file, the line that controls the sources for DNS should direct the name lookups to be from local files before any other naming source like bind

so you should have a line like this

```
hosts:          files dns mdns4_minimal
```

rather than this

```
hosts:          dns files mdns4_minimal
```